# Extract IPTC using ImageMagick without Entities but UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, imagemagick, iptc

I have an image containing ITPC data and use the following command to extract the IPTC as textual data:

```
convert image.jpg IPTCTEXT:iptc.txt
```

The problem is that this seems to be using entities for "special characters":

```
2#120#Caption="Beschreibung f&#195;&#188;r den Import aus IPTC"
```

Actually it should be "für" here. But instead of getting the correct entity &#252; for the "ü" character i get two entities (probably both bytes of the UTF-8 encoded character got transformed to entites separated). And these two entites i cannot parse correctly.

Is there any way to get the correct entity or disable the entities completely returning UTF-8 characters?

Edit:
I tried parsing the entities using StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml in Java but i get two characters ("Ã¼") instead of the "ü" as both entities are unescaped separated.

Edit2:
Example image here: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150615/5eiv6wwf.jpg

Comment: Can you provide the image with that text in it please?

Comment: Provided the link in the initial post.

Comment: Is this any better? `convert http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150615/5eiv6wwf.jpg 8BIMTEXT:-`

Comment: Sadly not. IPTCTEXT and 8BIMTEXT both have the "f&#195;&#188;r".

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable metadata package is IMHO exiv2 (http://exiv2.org/; available in all Linux distros, Windows, and not sure about Mac binaries).

See http://paste.fedoraproject.org/232538/34459066/ for results. ImageMagick is for metadata purposes not that great, I am afraid.

Comment: The easiest way to get `exiv2` on a Mac is with `homebrew`. Install `homebrew` by copying and pasting the one-liner on http://brew.sh and then run `brew install exiv2`. Job done!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are seeing something different from me. I am running ImageMagick 6.9.1-4 on a Mac under OS X.

If I do this:

```
identify -format "%[IPTC:2:120]" http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150615/5eiv6wwf.jpg
```

I get this:

```
Beschreibung für den Import aus EXIF
```

[image]

And if I hex dump that, I get this:

[image]

I think it may be related to your Terminal's locale settings - although I don't know why it still happens when you redirect to a file. Have you tried things like:

```
LC_CTYPE=C identify -format "%[IPTC:2:120]" http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150615/5eiv6wwf.jpg | od -xc
```

Comment: Using the -format parameter i also get the correct result. The problem is that when retrieving all IPTC data using IPTCTEXT the result is incorrect (at least it seems incorrect for me).